# No Sound when using Google Chrome

Tags: kali-linux, audio, chrome

I am having a problem with my UserID getting no sound in Google Chrome Version 56.0.2924.76 (64-bit). I am using Linux kali 4.6.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.6.4-1kali1 (2016-07-21) x86_64 GNU/Linux.
I (root) login with userid to work in Chrome.

Here is what I tried so far:

- Delete Userid / re-add, userid with the following commands:
  useradd $user
  chsh -s /bin/bash $user
  xhost si:localuser: $user
  usermod -a -G audio $user
  su $user
  google-chrome-stable &
  Result: No sound.
- Checked pulseaudio, alsa  there is no muted  volume.
  Sound in settings is **not** muted.
- I have  only 1 Flash Plugin enabled.

The sound is muted in Chrome on all apps requiring sound ex; Youtube.
I can get sound with userid if Chrome is launch with the “No Sanbox.

I don’t believe my sound card is the problem but below is a list. 
Aplay -l

**List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices:**

```
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3263 Analog [ALC3263 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Works on Ubuntu and Kali Linux

```
killall pulseaudio
rm -r ~/.config/pulse/*
rm -r ~/.pulse*
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is in fact just one or two websites that have the problem, last week you might have simply right-clicked a tab, and selected "Mute site", and forgot about it.

So simply right click the tab with the problem, and click "**Unmute site**".